# XSL cross reference

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am stuck with a XSLT 1.0 problem. I tried to find info on StackOverflow but I couldn't apply the examples.

Here is the structure of my XML:

```
<XML>
<PR>
    <AS>
        <ID_AS>AS-001</ID_AS>
        <FIRST>
            <ID_CATALOG>Id-001</ID_CATALOG>
            <STATUS>NOK</STATUS>
        </FIRST>
        <SECOND>
            <ID_CATALOG>Id-002</ID_CATALOG>
            <STATUS>OK</STATUS>
        </SECOND>
    </AS>
    <AS>
        <ID_AS>AS-002</ID_AS>
        <FIRST>
            <ID_CATALOG>Id-003</ID_CATALOG>
            <STATUS>OK</STATUS>
        </FIRST>
        <SECOND>
            <ID_CATALOG>Id-004</ID_CATALOG>
            <STATUS>OK</STATUS>
        </SECOND>
    </AS>
</PR>
<METADATA>
    <ID_CATALOG>Id-001</ID_CATALOG>
    <ANGLES>32.25</ANGLES>
</METADATA>
<METADATA>
    <ID_CATALOG>Id-002</ID_CATALOG>
    <ANGLES>18.75</ANGLES>
</METADATA>
<METADATA>
    <ID_CATALOG>Id-003</ID_CATALOG>
    <ANGLES>5.23</ANGLES>
</METADATA>
<METADATA>
    <ID_CATALOG>Id-004</ID_CATALOG>
    <ANGLES>12.41</ANGLES>
</METADATA>
</XML>
```

I want to display for each AS, the FIRST/ID_CATALOG, FIRST/STATUS and ANGLES corresponding to the ID_CATALOG, then SECOND/etc.

The output would be similar to:

> - AS-001
>
>   - Id-001 NOK 32.25
>   - Id-002 OK 18.75
> - AS-002
>
>   - Id-003 OK 5.23
>   - Id-004 OK 12.41

I tried the following XSL but I only get the ANGLES for the first item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:hma="http://earth.esa.int/hma" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
<!--==================MAIN==================-->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            AS List:
            <br/><br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="ASandCo"/>  
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<!--==================TEMPLATES==================-->
<xsl:template name="ASandCo">
    <AS>
        <xsl:for-each select="XML/PR/AS">
            <xsl:value-of select="ID_AS"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:value-of select="FIRST/ID_CATALOG"/> - <xsl:value-of select="FIRST/STATUS"/> - 
                <xsl:if test="contains(/XML/METADATA/ID_CATALOG, FIRST/ID_CATALOG)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/XML/METADATA/ANGLES"/>
                </xsl:if>
            <br/>
            <xsl:value-of select="SECOND/ID_CATALOG"/> - <xsl:value-of select="SECOND/STATUS"/> - 
                <xsl:if test="contains(/XML/METADATA/ID_CATALOG, SECOND/ID_CATALOG)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/XML/METADATA/ANGLES"/>
                </xsl:if>
            <br/><br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </AS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT will be applied to very large XML files, so I am trying to find the most efficient way.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Are you able to update your question with the XSLT that you have tried?

Comment: I think you need a Munechian Grouping for that. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Hello guys, I have updated my post to include the XSL I am trying to work out.

Comment: You need to read up on the `xsl:key` element and the key() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to look up some metadata metadata based on the ID_CATALOG value.

An efficient way to do this is by using a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)**. You can define a key on the top level:

```
<xsl:key name="metadata-by-id_catalog" match="METADATA" use="ID_CATALOG"/>
```

And then you can look up the ANGLES value using the key for a given ID_CATALOG value like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('metadata-by-id_catalog', FIRST/ID_CATALOG)/ANGLES"/>
```

and this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('metadata-by-id_catalog', SECOND/ID_CATALOG)/ANGLES"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I used the 'key' function as decribed in your example Jukka and it worked. Thank you so much for your help.